# What are the system tables used in Sql Server replication?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the system tables used in Sql Server replication?

Answer (score 4):

From [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179855%28SQL.90%29.aspx)...

Replication Tables in the **master** database...

- MSreplication_options

Replication Tables in the **msdb** database...

- MSagentparameterlist
- MSdbms
- MSdbms_map
- MSdbms_datatype
- `MSdbms_datatype_mapping`
- MSreplmonthresholdmetrics
- sysreplicationalerts

Replication Tables in the **distribution** database...

- MSagent_parameters
- MSagent_profiles
- MSarticles
- MScached_peer_lsns
- MSdistpublishers
- MSdistribution_agents
- MSdistribution_history
- MSdistributiondbs
- MSdistributor
- MSlogreader_agents
- MSlogreader_history
- MSmerge_agents
- MSmerge_history
- MSmerge_sessions
- MSmerge_subscriptions
- MSpublication_access
- MSpublicationthresholds
- MSpublications
- MSpublisher_databases
- MSreplication_objects
- MSreplication_subscriptions
- MSrepl_commands
- MSrepl_errors
- MSrepl_originators
- MSrepl_transactions
- MSrepl_version
- MSsnapshot_agents
- MSsnapshot_history
- MSsubscriber_info
- MSsubscriber_schedule
- MSsubscriptions
- MSsubscription_properties
- MStracer_history
- MStracer_tokens

Additionally, these tables in the **distribution** database are used for replicating data from non-SQL Server publishers...

- IHarticles
- IHcolumns
- IHconstrainttypes
- IHindextypes
- IHpublications
- IHpublishercolumnconstraints
- IHpublishercolumnindexes
- IHpublishercolumns
- IHpublisherconstraints
- IHpublisherindexes
- IHpublishers
- IHpublishertables
- IHsubscriptions

Replication tables in the **publication** database...

- MSdynamicsnapshotjobs
- MSdynamicsnapshotviews
- MSmerge_altsyncpartners
- MSmerge_conflicts_info
- MSmerge_contents
- MSmerge_current_partition_mappings
- MSmerge_dynamic_snapshots
- MSmerge_errorlineage
- MSmerge_generation_partition_mappings
- MSmerge_genhistory
- MSmerge_identity_range
- MSmerge_metadataaction_request
- MSmerge_partition_groups
- MSmerge_past_partition_mappings
- MSmerge_replinfo
- MSmerge_settingshistory
- MSmerge_tombstone
- MSpeer_lsns
- MSpeer_request
- MSpeer_response
- MSpub_identity_range
- sysarticlecolumns
- sysarticles
- sysarticleupdates
- sysmergearticlecolumns
- sysmergearticles
- sysmergepartitioninfo
- sysmergepublications
- sysmergeschemaarticles
- sysmergeschemachange
- sysmergesubscriptions
- sysmergesubsetfilters
- syspublications
- sysschemaarticles
- syssubscriptions
- systranschemas

Replication tables in the **subscription** database...

- MSdynamicsnapshotjobs
- MSdynamicsnapshotviews
- MSmerge_altsyncpartners
- MSmerge_conflicts_info
- MSmerge_contents
- MSmerge_current_partition_mappings
- MSmerge_dynamic_snapshots
- MSmerge_errorlineage
- MSmerge_generation_partition_mappings
- MSmerge_genhistory
- MSmerge_identity_range
- MSmerge_metadataaction_request
- MSmerge_partition_groups
- MSmerge_past_partition_mappings
- MSmerge_replinfo
- MSmerge_settingshistory
- MSmerge_tombstone
- MSpeer_lsns
- MSrepl_queuedtraninfo
- MSsnapshotdeliveryprogress
- MSsubscription_properties
- sysmergearticlecolumns
- sysmergearticles
- sysmergepartitioninfo
- sysmergepublications
- sysmergeschemaarticles
- sysmergeschemachange
- sysmergesubscriptions
- sysmergesubsetfilters
- systranschemas